# Cannot set watchpoint in GDB

Tags: debugging, gdb, watchpoint

I am doing debugging and wanted to check the place where the value of the variable changes .For this I tried setting a watch point by saying something like watch 'structure->somefunc.getvalue()' which is not a simple variable (probably some portion of a bigger structure invoking a function ) .When I do this gdb says No symbol 'structure->somefunc..' in current context .When I do a grep in the same directory I get 3-4 instances of the same expression.Am I missing out something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I missing out something?

Yes, you appear to be missing at least a couple of things:

- The expression `structure->somefunc.getvalue()` doesn't make any
  sense. You probably meant `some_variable->some_field.getvalue()`
- For that expression to be valid, you *must* be in a context where `some_variable` exists. The fact that `some_variable` shows up in `grep` output doesn't mean GDB can *currently* evaluate it. It may be able to evaluate it *when* you stop the program in correct context.
- It makes no sense (and is impossible) to set a watchpoint on return value of `getvalue()`. Watchpoints only make sense if you can specify *memory* location that you want to watch. If (as is likely) `getvalue()` returns something like `this->m_value`, then what you really want is to set a watchpoint on `*(&some_variable->some_field.m_value)`.